# Ubuntu 15.10 boot issue in virtual box

Tags: boot

I am running ubuntu 15.10 on Virtual Box.
Today when I reboot it, it didnt boot!
Says:

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal 
/dev/sda1: clean, some values/some values, etc.
```

[image: boot image]

It was getting stuck on this. so i tried booting in recovery mode and in **systemd** mode.
It booted up but after inserting password there is no desktop. I can't even right click.
I just reached terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + F1.

What I tried(According to searches):

> clean
>   update
>   upgrade
>   configure dpkg
>   and some more regarding packages

And ya. 2 days back while working I got an issue so I **switched back to upstart**. After that I didn't shutdown my ubuntu, I just suspended it.
Today when I rebooted it gave me this error.

Thinking that it could be an upstart issue **I reverted back to systemd again**. Now it can boot upto lockscreen but again.. no desktop after inserting password.

I reverted from GDM to lightdm also.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to the site! At the moment, your question is a bit imprecise. How could you do any changes to your system when you claim it didn't boot? Do you just mean theGUI? Please elaborate. Also, "and some more regarding packages" is not really a description that is going to make searching the root cause of your problems easier...

Comment: Initially it wasn't booting, But it booted through recovery mode(GRUB).  But  after logging in it shows black screen.  So, I pressed ctrl+alt+F1 on login screen to access terminal.  From there I swithed back to systemd.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! After a lot trials I managed it to work. I reinstalled xserver and nouveau. Though I had also updated Unity to 8 before thinking that it might have corrupted. :P So if anyone is having same issues can do this ;)